# Why is my child React component not receiving context?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

My icon component doesn't receive the context data when using useContext.

As you can see in these screen captures of the React developer tools, my parent component `<BreadCrumb>` component as well as sibling component `BreadCrumbItem` are receiving the theme context but for some reason my `Icon` component does not.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. I'm currently using Storybook to render this as a story so the theme provider is being added as a decorator in the `preview.tsx` file.

Here is the icon component as well. Boggling my mind...

```js
const Icon = ({
  size = 'small',
  fill = 'primary',
  secondaryFill = 'secondary',
  children: child,
  style,
  ...restProps
}: IconProps) => {
  const tokens = useThemeToken();
  const width = sizes[size].width;
  const height = sizes[size].width;

  if (fill === 'primary' || fill === 'secondary') {
    fill = tokens?.[fill] || '#000';
  }

  if (secondaryFill === 'primary' || secondaryFill === 'secondary') {
    secondaryFill = tokens?.[secondaryFill] || '#000';
  }

  const combinedStyle = {
    ['--primary-color' as string]: Object.keys(svgGradients).includes(
      fill as string
    )
      ? `url(#${fill})`
      : fill,
    ['--secondary-color' as string]: Object.keys(svgGradients).includes(
      secondaryFill as string
    )
      ? `url(#${secondaryFill})`
      : secondaryFill,
    '*': {
      pointerEvents: 'none',
    },
    ...style,
  };

  return React.cloneElement(
    child,
    {
      width,
      height,
      style: combinedStyle,
      ...restProps,
    }
  );
};

export { Icon };
```